# android change views on swipe

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I'm looking for a way to change the content of `TextViews` when the user swipes the layout holding those Views. My goal is something like that:
[image]

I'm trying to do this with a `SimpleOnGestureListener`(code goes below). The problem: when I swipe from left to right, the value of i becomes -1 and no reaction occures of following swipes. Right to left swipe causes i to become 1 (where the hell is zero?) and the View stops reacting on swipes again. What am I doing wrong?

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
public View mainview;
public TextView lol;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    mainview = (View) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
    lol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    mainview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        int i = 0;

        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
            return false;
        }

        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            i++;
            lol.setText("Text" + " " + Integer.toString(i));

            return true;
        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            i--;
            lol.setText("Text" + " " + Integer.toString(i));

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: how abt using gallery with custom adapter ?

Comment: could you give some more info please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786769/android-custom-gallery-view-set-own-border , google u will find many links and tutorials, in simple words add a GalleryView to your activity, set a Custom adapter (extend baseadapter) to the gallery . In adapter getview , inflate the layout with textview and bg and all and set value based on index .. Good luck.. no need of managing gestures , Note: gallery is deprecated and Viewpager/ HorizontalScrollview is preferred now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [viewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)? It does exactly what you need and supports indicators. There are some custom libs with indicators where you can find exact indicator you need, e.g. [this one is nice](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of managing gestures use a Gallery or Horizontal ScrollView or ViewPager